# Regex with negative lookahead limited length

Tags: regex

I have some text that looks like this:

```
UPPERCASE TEXT {wildcard amount of text} {Anchor word}
```

With this pattern repeating multiple times. I want to extract these multiple matches, which I can do with

```
[A-Z][A-Z ]+.+anchor
```

However I don't want it to match if there is UPPERCASE text within the wildcard text. I can check for this with a negative lookahead

```
[A-Z][A-Z ]+(?!.+[A-Z][A-Z ]+).+anchor
```

However the lookahead matches with all the other matches and cancels out. I can put limits on the size of the lookahead however sometimes the distance between uppercase words and the anchor is small and sometimes it is large, so I can't match everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your positive lookahead you don't need the + operand. You want it to fail if there is two or more characters, this is equivalent to failing if there is two characters.
- Your negative lookahead needs to be tested every char in the intermediate section.

https://regex101.com/r/tcxch6/1

Comment: Thanks this is perfect for what I needed! I don't quite understand your second point, however, is the idea here that the * operand applying the lookahead to every section until it hits the anchor? So at each character it needs to positively match with "." and not match [A-B][A-B] looking one character ahead?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just match uppercase letters, then space, then any amount of not-uppercase characters, then space then the anchor?

```
/([A-Z ]+) ([^A-Z]+) (anchor)/
```

I guess the problem is that if the text is

UPPERCASE TEXT {wildcard OTHERTEXT etc} anchor

Then this will find OTHERTEXT as the first match. Maybe the answer is to fix it to the start of the line, like this

```
/^([A-Z ]+) ([^A-Z]+) (anchor)/
```

If that isn't right, I recommend giving some more examples of the input and the required matches, because the question isn't all that clear at the moment.

Comment: The problem here was that I didn't mind if the middle text had Title Case